# RT linux isr routine

Tags: multithreading, driver, real-time, interrupt

From RT linux isr function can't get CAN register values.
Iam using m_can.c driver for spi-to-can in RT-linux (5.15.52 kernel i applied 5.15.55 RT-linux patch). My can device has one watch dog interrupt configured. When this watch dog interrupt occurs every millisecond, the m_can_isr function is called.

err = request_threaded_irq(dev->irq, NULL, m_can_isr,IRQF_ONESHOT,dev->name, dev);

just before creating this thread i printed some CAN registers and iam able to get values, but same registers if i print inside m_can_isr() -939522904 this junk value iam getting.
iam not able to read m_can register value inside m_can_isr(). outside of m_can_isr() the value is reading properly .
I need assistance debugging this problem, please. I have no idea how to troubleshoot this.